# Can I execute multiple Parse Queries in a loop?

Tags: android, optimization, parse-platform, foreach

I'm working on a chat app for Android, and I need to create several different conversations with one message in all of these created conversations. In my code, it looks like that :

```
for (ParseObject receiver : receivers) {

    final ParseObject convQuery = ParseObject.create("Conversation");
    convQuery.put("from", fromUser);
    convQuery.put("to", receiver);
    convQuery.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {

            ParseObject messageQuery = ParseObject.create("Message");
            messageQuery.put("conversation", convQuery);
            messageQuery.put("author", fromUser);
            messageQuery.saveInBackground();

        }

    });

}
```

As you can see, I am executing multiple Parse queries in a `for` loop. I'm not sure if it's the good way to go... Will it work? Is it optimized? Or is there another better way to do what I want here?

Thanks!

Comment: The only optimization I can see is do you need to create a new `convQuery` for every `receiver?`

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, because they are different conversations - one to one user. But is it OK to use a for loop like that? Will the "for" loop wait for each queries to be executed?

Comment: The `saveInBackground` operation is asynchronous, meaning you can keep calling at and each request is placed into a queue for later operation on a separate thread. The loop will run without waiting.